# Website directory structure different from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, directory, structure

I am coding a website using java servlets and am using eclipse and tomcat. When I test it using localhost, it works fine. But when I am deploying it on my actual website, the directory structure is messed up and the files are not called properly.

My eclipse directory structure on localhost is

Project Name
.src/packageName/java files
.WebContent/HTML files.

When I make a call from the html files, I use the relative location and tomcat automatically knows to look in the src/packageName folder. For example, from the /WebContent/login.html page makes a onClick call as follows,
 . This will automatically trigger the java file in /src/packageName/welcome

When I am deploying it in my actual website, the WebContent/login.html is throwing an error WebContent/welcome file is not found. How do I tell my website to search in /src/packageName folder?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...have you been sure to package the application as a war for deployment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just transferred all the files using an FTP client. After reading your comment, I exported the project into a war file and will transfer this to my goDaddy account and unzip it there. You think that should be sufficient? I am a beginner at this.

Comment: Yes, normally to be able to deploy a java web application. All you have to do is bundle it up as a war (Web application Archive) or a ear (Enterprise Application Archive)

If you have no external dependencies that need to be configured, you r application should be able to run.

Comment: I see. I transferred the war file and unzipped it in the html/ folder of the goDaddy webserver. But, the same problem, relative path of java files, still exists.

Comment: Well that is a bit weird,
Normally you don't have to unzip the war yourself.
You are supposed to drop it in the webapps folder (in the case of tomcat) and  tomcat will automatically unzip and deploy it for you. (I don't know if you have been doing this).

And creating the war, eclipse can help you bundle the application as  a war by selecting export as war.